# Limit Calls made by Rest Template per minute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

`enter code here`I am calling an API successfully using Rest Template. However, I have found that the API rate limits me to only 8 calls per minute, returning a 429 error after 8 calls. Is there any way to limit the number of calls made by Rest Template in a minute?

I have tried using the RateLimiter guava dependency but that has not helped

Code Snippet of the lambda function I'm using to call the API

```
responseEntity = object.stream().map(dataFeedInformation -> {
  try {
    return restTemplate.exchange(dataFeedInformation.getDataElement().get(0).getDownloadURL(), HttpMethod.GET,
        dataFeedRestClient.getHttpEntity(), new ParameterizedTypeReference<AccountPlanItemDto>() {
        });
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: after 8 calls you wanna queue them? or fail them and also can you show the code?

Comment: It would help if you pasted in your code.

Comment: Have you tried scheduling it with a frequency that doesn't exceed 8/min?  Using `ScheduledExecutorService` or similar for example?

Comment: Hi I want to store them in the responseEnity which is: List<ResponseEntity<Object>>

Comment: Use thread.sleep(7500). Although its not recommend solution as, thread sleeps by holding lock. Try if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my Solution:

```
while (responseEntityList.size() < listOfDownloadUrls.size()) {
      if (responseEntityList.size() > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(60000);
        numberOfIterations++;
      }
      for (int iterations = numberOfIterations * 20; iterations < (numberOfIterations * 20) + 20; iterations++) {

        if (responseEntityList.size() == listOfDownloadUrls.size()) {
          break;
        }
```